Is it correct to say "writing handwriting words" or "writing cursive words"?
Pupils in the first grade in Vietnam learn that there are 2 types of writing: the one that printed out and the one that is produced by hand.
For example, printed letter b looks like "b" and the counterpart produced by hand looks like the below picture.

Pupils have to use books with squares like that to write. Each big square has 16 tiny squares. They have to take into account how to position the letter in the tiny squares correctly like the example.
For example, the handwriting "b" must measure 5 tiny squares by 2.5  tiny squares. They will lose mark if they make the height of "b" 6 squares or the width 3 squares.
It seems western countries don't teach their children that way.
My question is:
Is the word "ba" in the above picture called a "handwriting word" or "cursive word" in general English?
"cursive" is a little too much because the "b" in the picture does not slant.
Or Do you have a word for this kind of writing?

In English, these are sometimes distinguished as hand-printed block letters, and cursive manuscript or cursive handwriting. However, look up synonyms, as usage varies in the English-speaking world. There are various "schools' of writing that have copyright for some!

That way of teaching writing is used in at least one Western country. In your country it is, surely, a historic legacy of the French colonial system. From approx 1900, the method you describe has been taught in French schools, and is called l'écriture droite. They use those squared books.

One note: "Cursive" can be an adjective: "The cursive writing in the letter was legible," but "handwriting" is always a noun. There's the adjective "handwritten." But both are more about the fact that a human is writing than the style. That is, there is such a thing as "cursive handwriting." Or a "handwritten" letter that is not in cursive.

Also: At least in the US, there is great debate over whether cursive should be taught, with strong feelings and lots of policy changes in both directions. Just google "should cursive be taught in schools" for more.

Finally: when we are writing by hand but not using cursive, there can be many varying personal styles, but this is often referred to generally as "printing," even though it's understood that we're talking about handwriting. For instance, on a form, it might ask you to sign your name, and then to print your name; you would be expected to use clear, Roman-style, unjoined letters.

"cursive" can be used to describe a style of handwriting, not a word, so you might say "Write 'ba' in cursive handwriting"  Or "The word 'ba' written in cursive handwriting".
There are many cursive styles, not all of them slant.
But you don't need to repeat yourself; you might say "Write 'ba' in cursive"  Or "The word 'ba' written in cursive".
In the UK, styles of writing in which the letters are connected are called "joined-up".  There are many styles of joined up: Cursive, copperplate, italic, Spencerian, Nelson...
The skill of handwriting is called "penmanship" and the art of beautiful writing is "calligraphy".
